# How to change color of a text field in pdfclown?

Tags: java, pdf, colors, pdfclown

I want to fill in a PDF form. I am using library Pdfclown for this.

I have a problem changing the color of a `TextField`. I can change font size without problems, but not the color of the text.

I put the code where I managed to set values in the PDF form:

```
public void setPDF(String Valor, String aField) {
    Form form = document.getForm();

    for (Field field : form.getFields().values()) {
        if (aField.equals(field.getName())) {
            DefaultStyle style = new DefaultStyle();
            style.setForeColor(DeviceRGBColor.get(Color.red));
            String newValue = Valor;                 
            field.setValue(newValue);                        
            style.apply(field);
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DefaultStyle` applies itself to `TextField` instances like this:

```
...
if(isGraphicsVisibile())
{
    composer.beginLocalState();
    composer.setLineWidth(lineWidth);
    composer.setFillColor(getBackColor());
    composer.setStrokeColor(getForeColor());
    composer.drawRectangle(frame, 5);
    composer.fillStroke();
    composer.end();
}
...
```

*(`apply(TextField)` in [DefaultStyle.java](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/clown/code/trunk/java/pdfclown.lib/src/org/pdfclown/documents/interaction/forms/styles/DefaultStyle.java))*

Thus, you might have to set

```
style.setGraphicsVisibile(true);
```

before applying your `style` to `field`.

Comment: Thanks 'mkl'. Applying your solution has changed textfield frame's foreground not the text. But anyway, for my application it is good enough for the time being.

Comment: Ah, I see. Once you asked for the text color, more often, though, for the text field color. I mainly thought of the latter...

Comment: I looked at the code once more. As far as I can see, black / default is hardcoded as text color.

Comment: @XabierFernandez Thus... Did my answer solve your question? Or are there any issues left

Comment: Hi mkl, thanks for your answer. Pity I can't give you a positive vote, I am a newbie.

Comment: As it is your question, you should be able to accept an answer... there should be a tick on the left of the answer, if you click it, you mark the answer as accepted answer.